# Non-numeric value error in Laravel 6 application

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-6

**Non numeric problem**

**This my php code**

```
<ul class="product_marks">
    @if($row->discount_price == NULL)
        <li class="product_mark product_discount"
        style="background: green;">NEW</li>

    @else
        @php
        $amount=$row->selling_price - $row->discount_price;
        $discount=$amount/$row->selling_price * 100;
        @endphp
        <li class="product_mark product_discount">

        {{intval($discount)}}%
        </li>
    @endif
</ul>
```

**Error:**

> A non-numeric value encountered in my view file

What's the problem.

Comment: can you show the error ??

Comment: A non-numeric value encountered..thats my error  view file  ..

Answer (score 0):

Check type all of these variables:

```
$amount=$row->selling_price - $row->discount_price;
$discount=$amount/$row->selling_price * 100;
```

It could be a string or `null`.

Answer (score 0):

First check the type of these attributes:

```
$row->discount_price
$row->selling_price
```

Then you can check again on the final result like that:

```
{{is_numeric($discount) ? $discount : ''}}
```